# How do I add data to core data NSManagedObject?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I want to make a simple app that calculates salary. User enters their expenses, etc and it will determine how much their income needs to be to make it work.

So I have it setup like so.  Entity is `Event` and it has attributes `Housing`, `Car Payment`, `Loan`, `Utilities`, and `Credit Card`, and finally `Income Requirement`.

So basically, when user starts this process, they will enter data for each of these values, then `Income Requirement` will simply be all of these added together, plus 30% of so for taxes, etc.

The way I'm doing it is creating the object when this process is started and save timeStamp to use as name, then as it pushes to the next VC, the related attribute is saved.  Then finally I need to calculate the `Income Requirement` attribute buy adding the rest, so how can I do that  part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, set `incomeRequirement` to be transient. Then, in your `NSManagedObject` subclass, define the getter as follows:

```
-(NSNumber*)incomeRequirement {
       double h=[self.housing doubleValue];
       double l=[self.loan doubleValue];
       return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:h+l];
}
```

This automatically calculates the sum whenever you access `incomeRequirement`.